# How to Slice Pandas dataframe based on corresponding ndarray

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas dataframe `df1` with x rows. I also have a numpy.ndarray `n1` with x rows.  `n1` has only one column, with values of either 0, or 1. I want to pick only the first column of the dataframe `df1`, where the corresponding ndarray column has value 1. How can this be done ?

The use case is like this :- I have a invoice dataframe, whose first column is the customer code. I also have a ndarray which is the output of a scikit churn prediction, based on this invoice dataframe as input. The ndarray has 1 for those invoices which has symptoms of churn and 0 for invoices which do not churn. So i want to extract customers who churn. Ofcourse the output will have repeated values of same customer, but that can be filtered.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data to clarify what you'd like?  Specifically, I'm confused by "I want to pick only the first column of the dataframe df1, where the corresponding ndarray column has value 1".  Don't you mean all columns where the ndarray column has a value of 1, like a boolean filter?

Comment: I have added the use case in question. I am using Scikit learn whose output is a ndarray of one dimension. I want the customer code from dataframe for those matching the array with value 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your indicators to booleans and then use boolean filtering.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
n1 = np.array([0, 1, 1])

>>> df1
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6


>>> df1[n1.astype('bool')]
   a  b
1  2  5
2  3  6
```